# compare value to multiple ranges in bash script and set other variables based on that match

Tags: string, bash

I am setting up a script in bash that in one part takes in an ip and based on that ip determines other network settings. 
Here is what I have

```
if[ 1 <= $net <= 5]
then
    network=10.1.0.0
    netmask=255.255.248.0
    gateway=10.1.0.1
elif[16 <= $net <= 23]
then
    network=10.1.16.0
    netmask=255.255.248.0
    gateway=10.1.16.1

elif[24 <= $net <= 31]
then
    network=10.1.24.0
    netmask=255.255.248.0
    gateway=10.1.24.1
elif[32 <= $net <= 39]
then
    network=10.1.32.0
    netmask=255.255.248.0
    gateway=10.1.32.1
```

.............. (it continues like that for a while.

Is there a better way to do this using case or something else?

I'm also not sure I am doing the IF statements correctly.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I guess I forgot to mention that the IP address is sourced from a "read" input that is then cut to get the value.

IE  user enters 10.1.40.207 wish is then piped to cut to get the $net=40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values can be calculated directly (as shown in other answer), that eliminates a lot of scripting; however, you may still need to check for valid/invalid input; but that also could be done w/o using an extended if/elif/else/fi.

But to answer the question, here's an if/else that can check for ranges of numbers (I don't think a 'case' would simplify matters):

```
#!/bin/bash

arg=$1

if  ((  1 <= arg && arg <= 5 )) ; then
  echo "from 1-5: $arg"
elif (( 16 <= arg && arg <= 23 )) ; then
  echo "from 16-23: : $arg"
elif (( 24 <= arg && arg <= 31 )) ; then
  echo "from 24-31: : $arg"
else
  echo "invalid : $arg"
fi
```

The main point is that `((...))` is used for arithmetic evaluation, not `[..]`; it's equivalent to `let` and returns true/false.

Sample output:

```
$ ./scr 1
from 1-5: 1

$ ./scr 7
invalid : 7

$ ./scr 23
from 16-24: : 23
```

Comment: Would this still work if the value was based on what I put in the EDIT: section of my post?

Comment: @DwarfCode Yes, it will still work; it doesn't matter where `$arg` comes from (prog arg, user input, file, etc). However, you may want to post details (or ask a separate question) if you run into problems: doing "read" with loops can sometimes be tricky depending on what you want to do. But all that is really a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

Set the values directly:

```
network=10.1.$(($net/8*8)).0
netmask=255.255.248.0
gateway=10.1.$(($net/8*8)).1
```

I've posted an explanation in steps on how I simplified your code into the above in 4 steps here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5585785/.

The "magic" is in the maths. A little maths prevents the need for any conditions. No `case`, no `if`s, no buts! :)

Comment: im confused by this response. Network and Gateway are fixed settings. they are for changing parts later that go into a file. They stay the same for a range of values.

Comment: Have you tried it? Do `net=25` and see what it says. Etc. See this **[live demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/POt5gp)** showing 5 random cases and their results. The trick is `$(($net/8*8))` rounds down to the nearest multiple of 8

Comment: Or... simply loop through all possible subnets if that's easier to see: **[http://ideone.com/Evgdz1](http://ideone.com/Evgdz1)** (Edited answer)

Comment: It changes the wrong value. Network and Gateway are fixed.Given any ip where x in 10.1.X.0 defines which network statement to do. IE 10.1.16.1 and 10.1.21.1  have the same network statement and gateway.

Comment: Huh. Derp. Wat. My code _doesn't_ derive `$net` - I treated it as a given. **Exactly** like your code did. The only three lines required are the top three. I'm sure you'll be able to work it out. See this pastebin spelling it out: **[http://paste.ubuntu.com/5585785/](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5585785/)**